# Armazenamento de dados local com React Native

Tags: react-native

Estou criando uma aplicação que necessita armazenar alguns dados localmente
São dados simples exemplo:

"DATA"
 "Local"
 "Umidade"
etc.

Como referência seria algo como ter um arquivo de dados ou melhor um banco de dados "localhost" onde eu guardaria uma série de dados básicos da aplicação. Sem conexão com uma API, ou internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dê uma olhada na API [AsyncStorage](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage#docsNav). Exemplo:

```
import { AsyncStorage } from "react-native";

let data_object = {
  data: '2018-08-01',
  local: 'Rua ...',
  humidade: 40,
};

// Armazenando dados
await AsyncStorage.setItem('DATA_KEY', JSON.stringify(data_object));

// Recuperando dados
const data = await AsyncStorage.getItem('DATA_KEY');
```

> No iOS, o AsyncStorage é baseado em um código nativo que armazena pequenos  valores em um dicionário serializado e valores maiores em arquivos separados. No Android, o AsyncStorage usa RocksDB ou SQLite com base no que estiver disponível.